# How can i return something from a function like this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, return

I'm quite new to typescript and have a fuction that will fetch user's steam inventory and store it in "inventory" parameter, but when i want to return it it will return undefined:

```
function getUserInv(steamid) {
    manager.getUserInventoryContents(steamid, 440, 2, true, function(err, inventory) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            return inventory
        };
    });
};

console.log(getUserInv('<my steamid>')) //returns undefined
```

How can i make it so that when i call it like above, it returns the inventory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can wrap it into a `Promise` like this

```
function getUserInv(steamid) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    manager.getUserInventoryContents(steamid, 440, 2, true, function(err, inventory) {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(inventory)
        };
    });
}
};

getUserInv('<my steamid>').then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this function returns a value *asynchronously*, you need to return a data type that can handle asynchronous values.

In JS, that is called a *promise*. You can access their value by registering a callback using `.then()`, or in TypeScript and other modern JS environments, you can use the nice `async/await` syntax.

Here is how you would create and return a promise from your function.

```
function getUserInv(steamid: string): Promise<Inventory> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    manager.getUserInventoryContents(steamid, 440, 2, true, function(err, inventory) {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(inventory);
        };
    });
  });
}

// Using .then():
getUserInv('<my steamid>').then(inv => console.log(inv));

// Using async/await:
console.log(await getUserInv('<my steamid>'));
```